# How can i search a array from a large array by numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am beginning at numpy! 
Has numpy some function can search an array from another one ,and return the similar ones? 
Thanks!

```
import numpy as np

def searchBinA(B = ['04','22'],A):
    result = []
    ?......?  numpy.search(B,A)?   "is this correct?"
    return result

A = [['03', '04', '18', '22', '25', '29','30'], ['02', '04', '07', '09', '14', '29','30'], \
          ['06', '08', '11', '13', '17', '19','30'], ['04', '08', '22', '23', '27', '29','30'], \
          ['03', '05', '15', '22', '24', '25','30']]

print(str(searchBinA()))


output:[['03', '04', '18', '22', '25', '29','30'], ['04', '08', '22', '23', '27', '29','30']]
```

Comment: Are those elements in each row of `A` unique? Are elements in `B` unique?

Comment: yes!each element in each row  of Ais unique ! but each row in A may not be unique! each element in b is also unique!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the inputs are NumPy arrays and that there are no duplicates within each row of `A`, here's an approach using [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) -

```
A[np.in1d(A,B).reshape(A.shape).sum(1) == len(B)]
```

Explanation -

1. Get a mask of matches in `A` against any element in `B` with `np.in1d(A,B)`. Note that this would be a 1D boolean array.
2. Reshape the boolean array obtained from `np.in1d(A,B)` to `A's` shape and then look for rows that have `n` matches for each row, where `n` is the number of elements in `B`. Since, there are unique elements within each row, the rows with `n` matches are the rows we want in the final output.
3. Therefore, sum the 2D reshaped boolean array along the rows and compare against `n` giving us a boolean mask, which when indexed into `A` would give us selective rows from it as the desired output.

Sample run -

```
In [23]: A
Out[23]: 
array([['03', '04', '18', '22', '25', '29', '30'],
       ['02', '04', '07', '09', '14', '29', '30'],
       ['06', '08', '11', '13', '17', '19', '30'],
       ['04', '08', '22', '23', '27', '29', '30'],
       ['03', '05', '15', '22', '24', '25', '30']], 
      dtype='|S2')

In [24]: B
Out[24]: 
array(['04', '22'], 
      dtype='|S2')

In [25]: A[np.in1d(A,B).reshape(A.shape).sum(1) == len(B)]
Out[25]: 
array([['03', '04', '18', '22', '25', '29', '30'],
       ['04', '08', '22', '23', '27', '29', '30']], 
      dtype='|S2')
```